# Is this RF Filter still current?

Tags: rf

I cannot find any information on this RF Filter, any help would be appreciated. Is this style still in use? type rf2168 rating #1
Is it Aviation related?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current as in "still currently made"? Almost certainly no, unless it's a military part still used by the military. Then it may not be made, but is still stocked somewhere, and would have a NSN issued. You can look up NSN numbers by manufacturer AFAIK.

But it could be easily enough reproduced. It looks like a part designed for use with aviation radios, or military radios. The wire terminals on the side facing the viewer are hermetic. The connector looks like it is at least waterproof. The connector on top of the filter is still made. There's nothing too "old" about the overall style, but there just may not be any application for this filter anymore.

Aviation radio hardware has advanced quite a bit since this filter was introduced probably 50+ years ago. If this is an aviation filter, it probably still flies in some old planes, so if you talked to companies that specialize in old aviation radio gear repair, perhaps someone there could tell you exactly where it was used.

You could use a RLC meter to try and characterize it at least a bit without destroying it. For a full characterization, a network analyzer would be needed, with appropriate fixtures.